# hibernate - force save before delete

Tags: java, hibernate, save

I have this information that I have to update on a table row before I issue the delete operation (a before delete trigger will take care of copying relevant data from the table). When I try to do the save and then delete from hibernate, hibernate will skip the save altogether. Sure... it makes sense to assume that it makes no sense to do the save operation if the entity is to be deleted.... but this is not the case as I just told you.

Committing the transaction before doing the delete could pull it off but that would mean that a new transaction would be required plus many more object I'm working with would have to be reloaded which makes it a no-go. Is there a way to adjust the definition of the entity so that the save operation is carried out before the actual delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should try `session.flush()` before `delete()`.

Comment: I didn't check back then if this was the answer.... _but_ given what I've learned since then this is the right answer.